# Tabulation in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm trying to make a script that takes data thanks to http request and then print some informations divided in two columns.
For example :

```
abcde            |   123
fghijkl          |   4567
mnopqrstuvwxyz           |   foo
```

As you can see, even with tabulation it doesn't work as I expected to...

Does anyone have an idea to solve this ?

Thanks by advance,

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
 cat file  | column -t -s' '

abcde           |  123
fghijkl         |  4567
mnopqrstuvwxyz  |  foo
```

Example is with a file containing your exact output in question, but you can pipe into `column` from any source.

- `-s` Specifies the delimiter (can be set of characters).
- `-t` Determine the number of columns the input contains and create a table.  Columns are delimited with whitespace, by default, or with the characters supplied using the `-s` option.  Useful for pretty-printing displays.

If you input doesnt contains separators ( in this case "|" ) you can use the following to insert desired separator.

```
cat file | sed 's/ /  |  /' | column -t -s' '
```

In the above `sed` im replacing  a single space with `"|"`
 ,   `sed` is matching first space and matches only one space at a line by default.

Comment: Looks like he would also like to use "-o '|' "

Comment: Thanks for the input Arron, Edited the answer. if you have a better way to add separator, Please share to improve the answer.

Comment: I don't think you need any `sed` there, I just had in mind that OP wanted the pipes to appear in the output. If that's the case, you'd have to specify the `-o` whether or not they are in the input (the separator being by replaced by the output separator, which is by default two spaces). The input MUST contain separator so that `column` can work on it (however that might be a single space ; no need to replace it with something else)

Comment: So if the non-aligned text contains pipes as separator, I would use `column -s '|' -o '|'`, and if it doesn't i would use `column -s '<whatever>' -o '|'`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my Column is complaining about `-o` and I cant find it in on man page, I'm on debian jessie.

Comment: Depends on the version it seems. [This one](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html) has it, [this one](https://linux.die.net/man/1/column) doesn't.

Comment: If there's no `-o` option I think keeping the separator is going to be tricky